# Select alternate rows from SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working with SQL Server 2008. I have a table which does not contain any unique columns; how to get alternate rows from it?

SQL Server table:

```
+-----+--------+
|  id |  name  |
|-----+--------|
|  1  |  abc   |
|  2  |  pqr   |
|  2  |  pqr   |
|  3  |  xyz   |
|  4  |  lmn   |
|  5  |  efg   |
|  5  |  efg   |
+-----+--------+
```

As we've to come with at least one working suggestion with the question, I've tried below code; which is not so proper technique when fetching from a huge amount of data.

Trial:

```
create table #tmp
(
    id int, name varchar(10), srNo int
)

insert into #tmp
   select 
      id, name,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) % 2 as srNo   --,alternate rows
   from 
      Employee

select * 
from #tmp 
where srNo = 1 --or srNo = 0
```

Above query gives out alternate rows i.e. 1st, 3rd, 5th *OR* 2nd, 4th, 6th etc.

Please help me out with **proper way** *without `#tmp`* to achieve the goal!

Comment: Try `SELECT ... FROM (<your SELECT query without INSERT INTO>) x WHERE x.srNo = 1`

Comment: How draw SQL Server table in post ?

Comment: @Kiquenet you can draw with the + and - signs as I have done in my post. You can click *Edit* to view actual text for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use your select statement as an in-line view. You don't need the #tmp table.

```
select t.id, name
from (select id, name, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) as srNo from Employee) t
where (t.srNo % 2) = 1
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/821f4/1)

Comment: @Vikrant I didn't have a SQL server to test it on. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 4):

--To fetch ALTERNATE records from a table (EVEN NUMBERED)

```
Select * from TableName where ColumnName % 2 = 0
```

For Eg : select * from HumanResources.Employee where BusinessEntityID % 2 = 0

--To fetch ALTERNATE records from a table (ODD NUMBERED)

```
Select * from TableName where ColumnName % 2 = 1
```

For Eg : select * from HumanResources.Employee where BusinessEntityID % 2 = 1

Comment: In table of SQL we have columns and under each columns we insert records row by row. Please try this query once. it will give you exact result @jww

Comment: In case of deletion of a row that has a BusinessEntityID an odd value, when this query is performed it will return two consecutive rows(contrary to the requirement) and vice versa for even value is also True

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking student as a table name.

Here is my answer ->

1. **For Even Row Number** -

`> SELECT id from (SELECT rowno, id from student) where mod(rowno,2)=0`

2. **For Odd Row Number** -

`> SELECT id from (SELECT rowno, id from student) where mod(rowno,2)=1`

Answer (score 0):

Same also can be achieved using **`having`** clause; but it adds `group by` task:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM (SELECT id, name, ROW_NUMBER()over(order by id) AS srNo FROM Employee) x
GROUP BY srNo, id, name
HAVING (srNo % 2) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use your select statement as an in-line view. You don't need the #tblCities table.

```html
select tbl1.CityID,tbl1.CityName from (select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by CityID asc) as row_no,CityID,CityName from tblCities) as tbl1  where tbl1.row_no%2=1
```

Comment: Your answer is no different than [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29316928/3682162)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare  @t table
    (
        id int,
        name nvarchar(20)
    )
    insert into @t
    Select 1, 'abc'
    union all
    Select 2, 'pqr'
    union all
    Select 2, 'pqr'
    union all
    Select 3, 'xyz'
    union all
    Select 4, 'lmn'
    union all
    Select 5, 'efg'
    union all
    Select 2, 'efg'

    Select * from(
    Select *, row_number() over(order by id) as rnum from @t ) t where rnum % 2 <> 0
```

Comment: You can use this code in SQL Server to find even or odd rows of a table. Just you need to change where condition based on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table t (id bigint NOT NULL, input_1 boolean not null, data_gps timestamp(0) not null);

insert into t (id, input_1,data_gps) values 
  (1, false  , '2022-01-01 15:42:07'),
  (2, true   , '2022-01-02 15:42:07'),
  (3, true   , '2022-01-03  15:42:07'),
  (4, false   , '2022-01-04  15:42:07'),
  (5, true   , '2022-01-05  15:42:07'),
  (6, true   , '2022-01-06  15:42:07'),
  (7, true   , '2022-01-07  15:42:07'),
  (8, true   , '2022-01-08  15:42:07'),
  (9, false   , '2022-01-09  15:42:07'),
  (10 ,true   , '2022-01-10  15:42:07'),
  (11, true   , '2022-01-11  15:42:07'),
  (12, true   , '2022-01-12  15:42:07'),
  (13, false   , '2022-01-13  15:42:07'),
  (14, true   , '2022-01-14  15:42:07');
```

you will have

[image: SELECT * FROM t]

Here is the query that will group by value change

```
select input_1, min(data_gps) as mind, max(data_gps) as maxd
from (
select input_1, data_gps,
     row_number() over (order by data_gps) 
     - row_number() over (partition by input_1 order by data_gps) as grp
from t
) as tmp
group by input_1, grp
order by min(data_gps);
```

The results

[image: Query results]

**DEMO**
https://dbfiddle.uk/6Ajy3H5O